# fancybox captions to left/right

Tags: jquery-plugins, fancybox, captions

I am trying to modify the captions in fancybox, as 1. I don't like the default display 2. the captions need to be longer than what is allowed by the default display.
What I aim to do, is to create 'inside' style captions, and move them to the right of the image.  I don't know how to do either, and am weary of messing with the css too much.  any ideas?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: fancybox2.  sorry for the late response.

Comment: fancyBox is not designed to put them left or right.